# Synchronizing View Model with Data Model in ASP.NET MVC 3.0

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

I have a solution that uses `Fluent nHibernate` for its data backend, and I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3.0` for my front-end. I thought I was clever with using a `Model View ViewModel` approach to solve something, but it has kind of backfired on me ...

Here is my Model.

```
class Alpha {
  virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  virtual string Name { get; set; }
  virtual IList<Delta> ListOfItems { get; set; }
}

class Delta {
  virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  virtual string Name { get; set; }
  // some other properties
}
```

Works great. Now here is my AlphaViewModel

```
class AlphaViewModel {
  string Name { get; set; }
  IList<Delta> ListOfItems { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a View Model to avoid conflict with **Proxies**. Since I know the first question will be "Your View Model looks just like your model, there is no point in using it". This works fine, but now here comes my problem.

Imagine the following process..

- User Creates **Alpha** through the use of an **AlphaViewModel**
- Database Saves **Alpha**
- User Adds new instance of **Delta** through the **ListOfItems** property
- Database Saves **Alpha**, along with new **Delta** items.
- User Edits **Alpha**
- User Deletes 1 instance of **Delta**
- Database goes to save...

Now we have a new problem. The database doesn't really know the `Id` of what it is changing.

I can add an `Id` to the ViewModel, but that really does not solve everything. I have seen how people handle this situation with **adding** new items, but I cannot find any good solutions that show them **deleting** them as well. Can anyone offer some insight?

I know this question has nothing to do with nHibernate, but since part of my reasoning does involve the nHibernate Proxies, I am including it as part of my tag strip since it may be part of the solution/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your form better. Don't you have "Remove" links or checkboxes for each item?

(imho it's a non-existant problem)

Comment: Removing them from the form isn't the problem - the problem is when it posts back to the Controller, synchronizing it with the database stored model.

Comment: I do not understand why. A proper view model for `Delta` would indicate which items that the user have selected for deletion (if you are using checkboxes). If you are using delete links, the `Delta` item would have been removed through ajax.

Comment: That isn't the point of the question. The data is stored in ViewModels, not the original models. The nested data is also a ViewModel. Synchronizing the nested data deletes the original data and re-creates new objects based on the ViewModel, thus causing association problems. I cannot just say `Session.SaveOrUpdate(viewModel);`. And if I use the assignment operator to assign the `Delta` objects to the owner, then it deletes the previous association when the database pushes it through.

Comment: The method you are describing only works if the ViewModel perfectly matches the underlying data, and it doesn't - it isn't supposed to.

Comment: No. I'm saying that you should use Id's to match the db model with the view model.